# Creating a video from NetLogo

Tags: video, netlogo, movie

Is there a way to create a video from NetLogo?

I have had a look at the quicktime extension, however, this seams to only allow you to import videos, not create them.

What I want to do is save a video of what is happening in the environment. I have a model with loads of turtles running around, I want to save this to a video so I can use it in a presentation. Is this possible (other than just doing a screen capture)?

Thanks

Comment: also asked at http://netlogo-users.18673.x6.nabble.com/Creating-a-video-from-netlogo-td5004837.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is documented at http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#movies

See also https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/issues/165 which just about everyone runs into, and https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/issues/499 which you may run into on Mac OS X.

An alternative approach is to use `export-view` and `export-interface` to save a bunch of PNG files, and then assemble them into a movie afterwards using other software.

Comment: @SethTissue  What is directory to which the movies are stored using  movie-grab-view, and can we change it using some command?

Comment: I think it defaults to the directory where the model file is, and I imagine [set-current-directory](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dict/set-current-directory.html) would work for changing that.

Comment: it seems to store in the same path where the model is present which is fine. There seems to be issue with size though I cant figure out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27912884/netlogo-video-capturing-file-size-and-format.