# NetLogo video capturing file size and format

Tags: video, netlogo

Following http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#movies . I created video of my model  comprising of run 2351 ticks. It created a video of size 1GB!. The video lasts only two and half minutes. I don't seem to understand why.
I tried varying frame-rate still the huge file size.
It gives a file-size of 560 Mb for a 10 sec movie! What am I missing something here?

Also, Is it possible to extract the video in some other format than .mov like .mp4 or .avi which are Windows friendly or VLC friendly? Simply changing the extension doesn't seem to do the job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected (though unfortunate) behavior — both the file size and the lack of flexibility around format.

It's covered at https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/issues/166. See also https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/issues/165. Summary: you'll have to use some separate tool to compress and/or convert the .mov file. Or, don't use the movie commands at all, use `export-view` or `export-interface` and use some separate tool to make a compressed movie from the resulting PNG files.

Comment: it is still unbearably slow in the end while exporting the movie.

Comment: True. I have added a note to that effect to issue #166.

Comment: Is there any way around this?

Comment: my ticks are aroung 100k, Doesn't seem quite viable option

Comment: go the `export-view`/`export-interface` route then

Comment: That would result in a large file and large time in building it. Are there any extensions or by linking with software I can accomplish the same.

Comment: Large time to build the file, probably. But large file? I don't think so. Third party software will be able to compress the movie as small as you want it, depending on what quality setting you use.

Comment: it works but is a rather cumbersome way to achieve something simplistic. If I may ask do you have plans of fixing this in the near future?

Comment: No. This is already stated and explained on the tickets I linked to.